# Display IEnumerable<dynamic> in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model as shown below. The MenuItem model, which has different SQL queries (MenuItem.MenuSQLQuery). 
I am executing these query agaist a progress DB and I want to display the result on the view. The return of the SQL query is IEnumerable dynamic (using dapper ORM).
Thanks for your time reading and appreciate any help.

Model

```
namespace Models.Menu
{
    public class MenuItem
    {

        public int MenuItemId { get; set; }
        public string MenuName { get; set; }
        public string MenuCategory { get; set; }
        public string MenuParent { get; set; }
        public string MenuAction { get; set; }
        public string MenuController { get; set; }
        public string MenuSQLQuery { get; set; }
        public string ResultColumnHeading { get; set; }
        public string MenuRole { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DataLayer;
using Models.Menu;

    namespace Controllers
    {
        public class BrowseController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

            public ActionResult BrowseResult(int menuId)
            {
                ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                var odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER=Progress OpenEdge 10.2B Driver;****DIL=READ UNCOMMITTED");

                // Open your connection


                //ApplicationUser currentUser = context.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
                var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                List<MenuUserAccess> menuAccess = context.MenuUserAccess.Where(m => m.MenuItemId == menuId).ToList();
                var access = menuAccess.FirstOrDefault(o => o.MenuUserId == userid);
                if (access != null)
                {
                    odbcConnection.Open();
                    var menuitem = context.MenuItem.First(m => m.MenuItemId == menuId);
                    var browseResult =  odbcConnection.Query(menuitem.MenuSQLQuery);
                    odbcConnection.Close();
                    odbcConnection.Dispose();
                    return View(browseResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the view I am using, but not getting any output.

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
<div>
    <h2>BrowseResult</h2>
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "BrowseResult";
        WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
        @grid.GetHtml()
    }
    else
    {
        <p> No Data Found</p>
    }

    <h2>End</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: what type is browseResult ?

Comment: IEnumerable<dynamic>

Comment: You want to set break points and debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it working.

This is my view code.

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>

<div>
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    <table class="table-striped">
        <tr>
            @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Model.ElementAt(1))
            {
                // This will be the column heading
                <td> <b>&nbsp;@kvp.Key &nbsp;</b></td>
            }
        </tr>
        @foreach (var d in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Model.ElementAt(i))
                {
                    //This will be the row data
                    <td>&nbsp;@kvp.Value &nbsp;</td>
                }
            </tr>
            i++;
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this

```
@model IEnumerable<dynamic>
<div>
    <h2>BrowseResult</h2>
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "BrowseResult";
        foreach(dynamic item in Model)
        {
            <span>@item.MenuName</span>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        <p> No Data Found</p>
    }

    <h2>End</h2>
</div>
```

Returns

> name1 name2

There's an example with WebGrid in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/webpages_webgrid.asp

Comment: Thanks Derloopkat. the w3scholls.com is a good one. But is it safe to have the SQL connection string, which has the DB user name and password to put in the view?

Comment: Only the name of the connection string can be placed into the view. Credentials are typically put in web.config. In your case, your connection string is hardcoded in your controller, hence it's compiled into the DLL for your web application. In any case, the client browser only gets resulting html.